# Solution for the 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a second order ODE of the form:

$f''+cf'+f(f-a)(1-f)=0$

How do I find its solution? I don't want the complete procedure. Just a hint will suffice.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean solution in the closed form? Mathematica gives nothing. You can also transform it into a system of first order ODEs and sketch its trajectories, to get a qualitative picture.

Comment: This is an equation of motion in a potential field with $V'(f)=f(f−a)(1−f)$ and linear friction with coefficient $c$. One has to expect an oscillating movement with steadily decreasing amplitude that ends at one of the minima of the potential, the extremal points of the set $\{0,1,a\}$. Except if the friction is too large, then it is a simple descent to the closest minimum point of the potential function.